# OpenVMS Record Management Services to Linux Replacement Recommendations

Tags: openvms

I am currently trying to find recommendations on how to migrate from OpenVMS RMS to Linux. Legacy code makes use of Indexed and Relative files. I currently have some ideas on how to move away from RMS and these include: Unix GDBM, Relational database (least likely to take this approach due to reluctance of adding this large of a complexity to the current project, and loading files into memory and working with them that way.

My question is if anyone has had any experience with this and if they are able to recommend a solution?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a product or library, an off-topic question. A quick search (`rms files on linux`) turned up [Sector7](https://sector7.com/s7/Vxtools/rms/vxrms.html), among others. I know nothing about them.

Comment: Indeed, check out Sector7 offerings and similar. Also have a look at one of the various ODBC (SQL) access to RMS files offerings notably by Connx or if you have access to it the EOL Attunity Connect set. The question is what will you try to retain? How were those RMS file accessed? Explicit RMS calls (from C perhaps) or build in Language support like  Cobol, Basic or Pascal?  You may want go Relational DB right away - possibly on OpenVMS itself first. How big? hundreds of programs and files? Terabytes? Good luck.

Comment: It's easy to map relative files on unix. The porting of indexed files depends upon how the indices are used. In a complex case, you may be forced to use a relational database. It's sad how file systems have regressed in Unix/windows from VMS and IBM mainframe systems.